# C preprocessor directives operator ##

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to create a function `void vec2_from_vec3(vec2 res, vec3 from)` in pure C, using operator `##` like so:

```
#define MAGIC_MACROS(n) \
void vec##(n-1)##_from_vec##n##(vec##(n-1) res, vec##n from);
```

but compiler woudn't let it. Is it possible?

Inspired by https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h/blob/master/linmath.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor won't evaluate/compute `n-1`, it will just expand it. Ex: `3-1`, so string concatenation won't work

(a modern compiler does it but it's already too late)

You can always do that which isn't that bad already:

```
#define MAGIC_MACROS(n1,n2) \
void vec##n1##_from_vec##n2##(vec##n1 res, vec##n2 from)
```

and use as:

```
MAGIC_MACROS(2,3);
```

Note that you shouldn't end your macros with `;`, so it's homogeneous with function calls and doesn't break editor auto-indentation.

Comment: Also, I want to create `typedef int16_t vec3i[3]` with `# define INT_BITS 16` and then ```# define LINMATH_H_DEFINE_VECI(n,b) typedef int##b##_t vec##n##i[n];``` and call `LINMATH_H_DEFINE_VECI(3, INT_BITS)`. But it changes to `typedef intINT_BITS_t vec3i[3]`. It's not possible too, right?

Comment: no for same reason: preproc only replaces once. You have to pass `(3, 16)`